# Resuming a global transaction in JTA

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, jta, xa

I have a little C program that connects to Oracle using OCI. I can start global transactions, suspend them, resume the same transaction in a different process, suspend again, commit back in the first process - all works fine. What I'd like to be able to do is inside my global transaction make a call to a Java app server, passing my Xid as a parameter, and have the web call do some work as part of the global transaction.

I've set up Glassfish 4.1 and I'm using eclipselink as the JPA implementation, but I don't see how I can use the passed in Xid to resume the original transaction. I'm guessing I need to use application managed persistence, so I have some code that looks like:

```
if (emf == null){
    emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("xaPU");
}
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();            
TransactionManager tm = (TransactionManager)ctx.lookup("java:appserver/TransactionManager");
```

I can then do:

```
tm.begin();
em.joinTransaction();
em.persist(data);
tm.commit();
```

And all the data is written to the DB but obviously this is done in a new transaction. If I get the transaction with:

```
Transaction tx = tm.getTransaction();
```

and look at tx in the debugger it seems to have a Xid set, but I don't see how I can set this Xid, or associate it with the Xid I pass in from my C program.

Am I on the right tracks with this, or is there an easier way to do this?